# Frequency Matrix with pivot table in excel

Tags: excel, matrix, pivot-table, frequency

I have a list of items and the number of times each item was ordered. I used this to calculate the frequency or probability that a single item will be ordered. However, I want to use this to create a matrix showing the probability of any 2 items being ordered together. There are 3035 items, so I was thinking a pivot table would be the best way, with the `Item_ID` listed as the columns and rows and then a probability matrix multiplying the 2 items' probabilities together, which I would then add some conditional formatting to make into a heat map.

**However**, when I try to make a pivot table like this, it only shows the multiplied frequency of the same 2 items. How do I fix this?

[image: Example of current pivot table]

[Pivot table fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PGC1h.png)

Comment: What are the formulas within your sheet?

Comment: @Capt.Krusty the data is pulled from a SQL database and downloaded into a CSV which I converted to an excel file, so the data itself does not include any formulas. However I updated the question to include a photo of the pivot table fields. Hope this helps!